# Best Way to Use Docker For Testing With Multiple Python Configurations

Tags: python, docker

The current workflow I have is that I created many images of different python setups, which people can pull from if they want to test a python script with a certain configuration. Then they build the container form the image and transfer the scripts, data, etc... from their local machine to the container. Next they run it in the container, and then they finally transfer the results back to their local machine.

I'm new to docker, so is there a better way to go about this? Something I have in mind that would be convenient is if there was a central machine or docker container where people could save their python scripts and data they need to run their tests and then run them in the image of the python environment they want to and save the results. Is this possible? I've been reading about volumes and think I can maybe do something with that, but I don't know...

Comment: Why Docker and not a Python-native virtual environment for this setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze I was using virtual environments before, but the issue was that all machines then had to set up virtual environments for all configurations and that wasn't ideal. Is there an easier way to do this using virtual environments that you had in mind?

Comment: Are the different environments for testing purposes (like making sure that the script runs on several different python versions) or do you just want to make several standard development environments available to a number of people?

Comment: @JeremyBare Testing purposes

Comment: In that case you might check out tox: https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Or some continuous integration solution which could make use of Docker and automate the testing process for you.

As for the problem of getting the virtual environments set up on each computer, you can use 'pip freeze' to generate a requirements.txt file for each environment and write a script to set up all of the environments for you when you prepare a new computer. This doesn't work as well if you are constantly changing the environments though in which case you might want to look for a docker CI solution

Comment: @JeremyBare Thanks! I'll look into those things